# Do I need a separate command when using an oracle?

Tags: corda

I want to issue something e.g. a new option. Inside the flow where I'm issuing this new option, I need to get info from two separate oracles that need to provide data for the output state.

How should I do this...  should I have one output and 3 commands? command with data from Oracle 1, command with data from Oracle 2 and then the issue command? or can this be done with one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely up to you - your command can contain whatever you data you want, so in theory, you could do the whole with one command.

Having said that, I would probably split it out into at least two commands for clarity and privacy. The privacy element is you can build a filtered transaction for the oracle to sign that only contains the oracle command.

If you don't mind the two oracles seeing the data sent to each for signing, you could encapsulate the data in one command e.g.

```
class OracleCommand(val spotPrice: SpotPrice, val volatility: Volatility) : CommandData
```

Where one oracle attests to spotPrice and the other to Volatility.

However, you would find it hard to determine what part of the data they attested to since they will both sign over the entire filtered transaction.

Unless you knew the design of the oracle could specifically pick out the correct data, you're probably better off going with three separate commands.